# Image sizes for android and iOS in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

While making iOS Apps, we generally used to supply @x,@2x,@3x images. And based on my knowledge in case of android, there was some approx six different sizes

I have started working on react-native and came across the image issue.

My Question are: Do I need to provide images with all different sizes (i.e. approx 6-7 image sets by combining iOS and android) Or only 1 image and rest will be taken care internally? Will it look blurred on higher resolution phones?

Thanks.

Comment: I think three images are enough already. Mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi for android, 1x 2x 3x for ios

Comment: `hdpi` is not a 2x scale. `hdpi` is 150% of `mdpi`. [See here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DesigningResources)

Comment: [Here are the React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html) on `PixelRatio` which explains the image sizing from their point of view.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You still need to provide multiple images. According to the [Images](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html) documentation, if you are using an image named `check.png`, you also have to include `check@2x.png` and `check@3x.png`.

Quoting:

> The packager will bundle and serve the image corresponding to device's
>   screen density. For example, check@2x.png, will be used on an iPhone
>   7, whilecheck@3x.png will be used on an iPhone 7 Plus or a Nexus 5. If
>   there is no image matching the screen density, the closest best option
>   will be selected.

Comment: is this worked for android with different screen size too?

Comment: same question here, is it applies for android?

Comment: Yes this convention works the same for Android. Notice the documents say "check@3x.png will be used on an iPhone 7 Plus or a Nexus 5." Well, Nexus 5 is an Android device. React Native makes managing assets real easy. Also, read this article for an even better way to store your static assets: https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/react-native-tips-and-tricks-2-0-managing-static-assets-with-absolute-paths

Comment: Just to be clear, yes, it does work on Android as well without need of any changes. From the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images): "Same system on Android and iOS."