# How to use android images for different pixel ratio in android? What should I use for hdpi images I can't use imageName@1.5x?

Tags: image, react-native, pixel-ratio

I have 5 images from designer mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhpdi as I found out that in React Native i can only give

1. check.png
2. check@2x.png
3. check@3x.png

I have read [Image sizes for android and iOS in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42282252/image-sizes-for-android-and-ios-in-react-native) but i don't how to provide hdpi(1.5x) and xxxhdpi(3.5x) images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simply don't need the intermediate ratio assets while working with React Native, `2x` and `3x` works very well for `hdpi>=` requirements. Technically speaking, when you bundle the RN project in Android or when it gets bundled while building, you will be able to see autogenerated transformed image assets in `android/app/src/res/drawable` which are required for the app to render on target screen resolutions. I would recommend observing those auto-generated assets after building the bundle, you will have fruitful insights about the asset distribution and usage.

Comment: Means we need to add only check.png, check@2x.png, check@3x.png. Then how to add mdpi image and hdpi image for android

Comment: Just add the `check.png, check@2x.png, check@3x.png`. This will be sufficient.